# Particle's not showing up in render mode ,view port

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, particles, blender-internal-render-engine

I have been struggling a lot working with the particles in my current practice. I have been trying out to make bubbles for a beer model in which

1. working as the fizz bubbles (the emitter is the *BUBBLES* plane)
2. top position bubble collector (the emitter is the *top* plane)
3. Bottom position bubble collector (the emitter is the *bottom* plane)

All the emitters are emitting the same object which is a low-poly icosphere with a glass shader(ico). The top and bottom have the same particle system, i.e *particle system 2*.

The problem is: none of the particles are visible to me not even in the viewport. The particles are only visible when the icosphere is in *Edit Mode*. Other than that it's not visible.

[image: wireframe]

[image: rendered]

Please help me with this being a beginner in Blender. I'm stuck and confused about what to do.

PS: Is it because of my current configuration? My config is: legion y520 laptop (16gbram, 1050ti, 128gb SSD+1tb HDD, Windows 10 home)

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!!

**Here is the link of my project**: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M_zQQH7q8c2TjDnpPaI7uGSSDc9Xq83T/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. make sure you are in object mode (you can change with TAB)

[image]

2. change your start frame to 1

[image]

3. select your bottom particle settings and change scale to 10 (you can later adjust this, but for now do it, so you can "see" something

[image]

[image]

4. start animation with SPACE

result:

[image]

so your scale was just too low, that's all.

Comment: Thank you so much @chris !

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem but solution was different. Posting in case someone else like me stumbles upon here.

[image: Tick this 'use modifier stack']

Tick this *Use Modifier Stack* under *Emission > Source* settings, would help if there are modifiers applied on mesh.